# Creating a http file uploader for swing

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a Java swing application that allows multiple file selection/uploading with progress bar attached to it. By its side, there will be a pause and resume button.

The upload should work asynchronously. The essence of this application is to upload PDF files to an online server or MySQL database.

Comment: If you're uploading to an external file server, you will need to use the file transfer protocol (FTP).  There are plenty of open source FTP programs.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Does it work?

Comment: Gilbert Le Blanc can refer me to one?